# MSSQL VIA FreeTDS, ODBC, and Cpanel Unknown host machine name (severity 2)

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc, cpanel

I have installed FreeTDS 0.91, ODBC, on a Cpanel server running Centos 6.5x64. Everything appears to be running fine and I can connect to the remote MSSQL 2012 server using:

```
/usr/local/freetds/bin/tsql -S sqlserver -U test -P mypassword
```

and succesfully execute queries in the database.

I can also connect through:

```
isql -v sqlserverdatasource test mypasswordhere
```

But for some reason `/usr/local/freetds/bin/tsql -LH server.ip.here`

returns no information or errors which doesn't make much sense when it is proven I can connect with the other methods above.

So now when running a test script from a cpanel account on the machine I get:

```
Unknown host machine name (severity 2)
```

Here is the test script:

```
//Database connection function.
function getConnection() {
    try {

    //$dbconnect = new PDO("sqlserver:Server=server.ip.here,1433;Database=dbname", "user", "password");
    $dbconnect = new PDO("dblib:host=server.ip.here,1433;dbname=dbname", 'user', 'password'); 
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "CONNECTION ERROR.<br>Error message:<br><br>" . $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
    if (!$dbconnect) {
        die('Cant connect to database. Please try again later!');
    }
    else{
        echo "i'm in!";
        return $dbconnect;
    }
}
```

The first commented line is the old one using sqlserv which I found did not work at all from what i can tell because of the x64 OS. I have also tried with `""` around user and pass as well as no marks at all.

`php -m` does show `PDO` and `pdo-dblib`.

Any ideas where I can look next?

Update: This was fixed. I missed in `freetds.conf`:

```
[global]
    # TDS protocol version
    tds version = 8.0
```

It was originally set to 4.5 instead of 8.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was with three steps:

First, I edited `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf` and changed the tds version like this:

```
tds version = 8.0
```

The second step was not entering port number. The port was already 1433, and not specifying it fixed the exact same issue on my case.

Lastly, to connect properly, I had to restart networking as @user1054844 [mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/a/525549/107722) as this:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

After all these steps, I was able to connect and work with the SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

You actually did not need ODBC at all since your connect script is using pdo_dblib not odbc. You can just install FreeTDS than enable pdo_dblib via the compile time flag in rawopts and rebuild via EasyApache. Of course cPanel specifics for this are a bit different.

I just did this for a friend and decided to document it since it is hard to find accurate clear information for FreeTds and pdo_dblib on cPanel.

Guide is here: [FreeTDS And pDO_dblib On cPanel](https://virtopia.ca/forums/topic/3-cpanel-install-freetds-and-pdo-dblib-for-mssql-support/)