# SQLSTATE[HY000] Unknown host machine name (severity 2) PHP 7.0

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Before someone downvote & flag this question as duplicate, I have already checked below questions but none are applied to my case;

[MSSQL VIA FreeTDS, ODBC, and Cpanel Unknown host machine name (severity 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249462/mssql-via-freetds-odbc-and-cpanel-unknown-host-machine-name-severity-2)

[php dblib, Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] Unknown host machine name (severity 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570235/php-dblib-error-sqlstatehy000-unknown-host-machine-name-severity-2)

I am getting this error after sometimes while it's been working fine previously.

What I do to fix this currently is to restart the PHP service by `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`. But this would come back after few days. Any idea?

I'm using Laravel 5.3 with PHP version below;

```
PHP 7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Below is the content of `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`;

```
    #   $Id: freetds.conf,v 1.12 2007/12/25 06:02:36 jklowden Exp $
    #
    # This file is installed by FreeTDS if no file by the same 
    # name is found in the installation directory.  
    #
    # For information about the layout of this file and its settings, 
    # see the freetds.conf manpage "man freetds.conf".  

    # Global settings are overridden by those in a database
    # server specific section
    [global]
            # TDS protocol version
    #;      tds version = 4.2
            tds version = 8.0

            # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
            # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
            dump file = /var/log/freetds.log
    ;       debug flags = 0xffff

            # Command and connection timeouts
    ;       timeout = 10
    ;       connect timeout = 10

            # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
            # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.  
            # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit 
            text size = 5242880

    # A typical Sybase server
    [egServer50]
            host = symachine.domain.com
            port = 5000
            tds version = 5.0

    # A typical Microsoft server
    [egServer70]
            host = ntmachine.domain.com
            port = 1433
            tds version = 7.0
```

Below is the output log from `/var/log/freetds.log`

```
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 5:
      REC[0xbd2738ac20]: Preparing Packet Application Data(23) with length: 338 and min pad: 0
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 9:
      ENC[0xbd2738ac20]: cipher: AES-256-CBC, MAC: SHA384, Epoch: 1
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 11:
      WRITE: enqueued 421 bytes for 0xbd27345690. Total 421 bytes.
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 11:
      WRITE FLUSH: 421 bytes in buffer.
    net.c:1242:in tds_push_func
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 11:
      WRITE: wrote 421 bytes, 0 bytes left.
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 5:
      REC[0xbd2738ac20]: Sent Packet[649] Application Data(23) in epoch 1 and length: 421
    dblib.c:4639:dbsqlok(0xbd271fa580)
    dblib.c:4669:dbsqlok() not done, calling tds_process_tokens()
    token.c:540:tds_process_tokens(0xbd27345690, 0x7ffd4b1c45a0, 0x7ffd4b1c45a4, 0x6914)
    util.c:156:Changed query state from PENDING to READING
    net.c:1201:in tds_pull_func
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 10:
      READ: Got 5 bytes from 0xbd27345690
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 10:
      READ: read 5 bytes from 0xbd27345690
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 10:
      RB: Have 0 bytes into buffer. Adding 5 bytes.
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 10:
      RB: Requested 5 bytes
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 5:
      REC[0xbd2738ac20]: SSL 3.3 Application Data packet received. Epoch 0, length: 96
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 5:
      REC[0xbd2738ac20]: Expected Packet Application Data(23)
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 5:
      REC[0xbd2738ac20]: Received Packet Application Data(23) with length: 96
    net.c:1201:in tds_pull_func
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 10:
      READ: Got 96 bytes from 0xbd27345690
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 10:
      READ: read 96 bytes from 0xbd27345690
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 10:
      RB: Have 5 bytes into buffer. Adding 96 bytes.
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 10:
      RB: Requested 101 bytes
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 5:
      REC[0xbd2738ac20]: Decrypted Packet[3886] Application Data(23) with length: 17
    net.c:557:Received header
    0000 04 01 00 11 00 73 01 00-                        |.....s..|

    net.c:611:Received packet
    0000 04 01 00 11 00 73 01 00-fd 10 00 c5 00 01 00 00 |.....s.. ........|
    0010 00                     -                        |.|

    token.c:555:processing result tokens.  marker is  fd(DONE)
    token.c:2339:tds_process_end: more_results = 0
                    was_cancelled = 0
                    error = 0
                    done_count_valid = 1
    token.c:2355:tds_process_end() state set to TDS_IDLE
    util.c:156:Changed query state from READING to IDLE
    token.c:2370:                rows_affected = 1
    util.c:104:logic error: cannot change query state from IDLE to PENDING
    dblib.c:4707:dbsqlok() end status is SUCCEED
    dblib.c:4718:dbsqlok() end status was success
    dblib.c:1668:dbresults(0xbd271fa580)
    dblib.c:1674:dbresults: dbresults_state is 5 (_DB_RES_SUCCEED)
    dblib.c:1657:dbresults returning 1 (SUCCEED)
    dblib.c:2761:dbcount(0xbd271fa580)
    dblib.c:1813:dbnumcols(0xbd271fa580)
    dblib.c:2761:dbcount(0xbd271fa580)
    dblib.c:1813:dbnumcols(0xbd271fa580)
    dblib.c:1443:dbclose(0xbd271fa580)
    dblib.c:258:dblib_del_connection(0x7f878af82780, 0xbd27345690)
    mem.c:615:tds_free_all_results()
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 5:
      REC[0xbd2738ac20]: Start of epoch cleanup
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 5:
      REC[0xbd2738ac20]: End of epoch cleanup
    net.c:1259:GNUTLS: level 5:
      REC[0xbd2738ac20]: Epoch #1 freed
    util.c:156:Changed query state from IDLE to DEAD
    dblib.c:305:dblib_release_tds_ctx(1)
    dblib.c:5882:dbfreebuf(0xbd271fa580)
    dblib.c:739:dbloginfree(0xbd273db3f0)
    dblib.c:1512:dbexit(void)
    dblib.c:305:dblib_release_tds_ctx(1)
```

edit: i found that this happen when there is so many records to be inserted in short time. but still don't know what is the cause.

Comment: cant find "ntmachine.domain.com" sure thats the right name, you do have to change the settings to match YOUR account?

Comment: @smith I don't think that is the cause because it is been working fine before